# Facebook Connect vs localhost

Tags: facebook

We are trying to build an app with Facebook Connect on the local server.

When we give the URL as follows, it still does not work on the local system:

[image]

Here are the errors I get:

> API Error Code: 191 API Error
>
> Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error
>
> Message: redirect_uri is not owned by
>   the application.

Comment: Have you also set the canvas URL to locaohost? You can also try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: nope. guess thats the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the same URL for Canvas url under core settings of your application settings